# App crashes when trying to use UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

When launching my tab-based app, it crash when I'm trying to navigate to a tab with a UITableView in it, probably due to Interface Builder wrong connection I've made.

I have absolutely no idea why... I'm getting crazy over here!

I've simplified my code so now it contains 2 tabs; when trying to navigate to the non-active tab, the app crashes with no further explanation.

I've posted the simplified source here: [source download](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/86840-tab-controller-problem.html).

Any help will b appreciated.

Comment: I do not have account in http://www.iphonedevsdk.com. Can you upload some other place from where I can download without having account ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get when it crashes?

Comment: @Deeps - the ansewer below fixed this already. tnx anyway.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez - something about key-value coding... according to some googling I've made it's indeed related to connection in the Interface Builder, as the marked answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the name of the UIViewController in tab. VideosGalleryViewController was not mentioned in the class. Check the screen shot attached.

[image]